# Using PDF annotations in code

Tags: unicode, acrobat

Does anyone use the annotations functionality of Adobe PDFs remotely? eg accessing them via script or COM?

I am having trouble with getting UNICODE info out of a pdf and wondered if anyone had come across similar issues?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well it turns out that we can get the Annotations out with unicode correctly if we use the javascript objects in the pdf COM interface.

This is now the approach we are taking.  A basic (VB) example can be found [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/VBJavaScript.pdf).